# Set property value of complex object with Unity during registration

Tags: c#, asp.net, unity-container

I have an Unity Container where I register `MyContext` (which extends `DbContext`) like this:

```
var _container = new UnityContainer();
_container.RegisterType<MyContext, MyContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

For this type I want to make sure that every instance of `MyContext` has `Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled` set to `false`.

I tried to pass the `InjectionProperty("Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled", false)` as param but that didn't work.

Is it possible to achieve what I want with Unity like this?